# Changing excel query source in vba based on a cells input

Tags: excel, vba

I have 30 queries saved in a document.  I then want a single sheet's information to be updated only by the query that the user has set in a specific cell.  This macro works great, but I need the query CHC to change based on whatever code they enter into a cell.  I tried just making a variable, but I keep getting errors when trying to use that variable within the macro.  Thanks for the help!

```
Dim RosterA As Variant
RosterA = "Query - " & Range("B3").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(RosterA).Refresh
Sheets("RosterFromA").Select
Cells.Clear

Range("A1").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""CHC"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [CHC]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query___CHC"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RosterFromA").ListObjects("Table_Query___CHC").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RosterFromA").ListObjects("Table_Query___CHC").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Table_Query___CHC[[#All],[Uniform NR]]"), SortOn _
        :=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RosterFromA").ListObjects("Table_Query___CHC"). _
        Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out the proper use of the quotes to make it take the variable as needed.  Here is what I ended up with.

Thanks

```
Dim RosterA As Variant
RosterA = "Query - " & Worksheets("PLAYERS HOME").Range("B3").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(RosterA).Refresh
Sheets("RosterFromA").Select
Cells.Clear

Range("A1").Select
Dim RosterATRI As Variant
RosterATRI = Worksheets("PLAYERS HOME").Range("B3").Value
Dim RosterAData As Variant
RosterAData = """" & RosterATRI & """"


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & RosterAData & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & RosterATRI & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query___" & RosterATRI
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RosterFromA").ListObjects("Table_Query___" & RosterATRI).Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RosterFromA").ListObjects("Table_Query___" & RosterATRI).Sort. _
        SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Table_Query___" & RosterATRI & "[[#All],[Uniform NR]]"), SortOn _
        :=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RosterFromA").ListObjects("Table_Query___" & RosterATRI). _
        Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```